# Prove that angle ACB > angle ABD.

Tags: geometry

here is the problem says
"In the triangle $ABC$, $AB > AC$. $AC$ is extended to $D$ so that $AD = AB$. Prove that angle $ACB >$ angle $ABD$."

I'm trying to solve by make equations using the fact that sum of triangle is $180$.
But I can't come up the fact that angle $ACB >$ angle $ABD$...

Comment: Try starting with a sketch and seeing what you can find.

Comment: Sorry guys, It was angle ABD not angle ABC;;

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, denote $ABC$ for angle $ABC$.

If you draw a graph, it is easy to see that $ACB=ADB+CBD$. Since $AB=AD$, $ABD=ADB$, so $ACB=ABD+CBD$. That proves the claim.

Comment: it was angle ACB > angle ABD sorry...

Comment: That's exactly what I just proved

Answer (score 0):

If you extend AC to AD and then look at the new triangle ABD, you see that this is an isosceles triangle. Therefore you will have that ABD = ADB. Call the measurement of angle A equal to x degrees. Then the measurement of angle ABD = ADB = $(180-x)/2$. It is clear that ABC must be strictly less than ABD (draw a picture to see this), and we get that $ABC < (180-x)/2$. But then this means that $ACB > (180-x)/2$, and so $ACB>ABC$. Drawing a picture will help.

Comment: it was angle ACB > angle ABD that I need to prove